# Datatable component in Angular 7 problem with responsiveness when fetch data from backend

Tags: angular, typescript, datatables, components, responsive

I've created a data table component in Angular which takes as input a configuration object that sets up the table and displays the table based on these configurations.

***My component works in 2 modes:***
1. You can provide data as part of the configuration file to display at the table.
2. You can provide API URL configured with paging responses in order to make datatable showing your data directly from backend with paging.

The format of the configuration file that my component need as input:

```
export interface DataTableConfig {
    remove?: action;
    more?: action;
    data?: Array<any>;
    pageSize?: number;
    ajax?: {
        URL: string;
        headers: HttpHeaders;
        pathToProperty: string;
        firstPage?: number;
    };
    columns: Array<column>;
}

interface column {
    title: string;
    data: string;
    width?: string;
    responsivePriority?: number;
    dateFormat?: String;
    orderable?: boolean;
    class?: string;
    icon?: {
        iconName: string;
        isTrue?: string;
        color?: string;
    };
}
```

The problem that I have is that I want some of the columns of the table to be hidden (class none) and when the user press the (+) button to show the hidden information.

I accomplished this at the first mode of the use of my data tables (provided data) but at the second case, when I fetch the data from the backend in pages the responsiveness of the columns is gone.  I can't understand why.

I am providing my html code and the construction of the configuration object of data table below.  Anyone know the solution?

**HTML CODE**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="dtOptions">
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="row-border hover">
<tbody>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let element of configuration.data">
    <tr>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let column of configuration.columns">
        <ng-container *ngIf="column.data && column.title && !column.dateFormat">
          <td>
            <div class="align-icon-text">
              <ng-container *ngIf="column.icon">
                <mat-icon [style.color]="column.icon.color" class="icon" *ngIf="showIcon(element,column)">
                  {{column.icon.iconName}}</mat-icon>
              </ng-container>
              <span *ngIf="column.data">{{showValue(element, column.data)}}</span>
            </div>
          </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="column.data && column.title && column.dateFormat">
          <td>
            <div class="align-icon-text">
              <ng-container *ngIf="column.icon">
                <mat-icon [style.color]="column.icon.color" class="icon" *ngIf="showIcon(element,column)">
                  {{column.icon.iconName}}</mat-icon>
              </ng-container>
              <span *ngIf="column.data">{{showValue(element, column.data) | date: column.dateFormat}}</span>
            </div>
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <td (click)="deleteRow(element)" *ngIf="configuration.remove && column.data=='remove' && !column.title"
          matTooltip="{{configuration.remove.tooltip}}">
          <button mat-icon-button>
            <mat-icon>{{configuration.remove.icon}}</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </td>
        <td (click)="showMore(element)" *ngIf="configuration.more && column.data=='more' && !column.title"
          matTooltip="{{configuration.more.tooltip}}">
          <button mat-icon-button>
            <mat-icon>{{configuration.more.icon}}</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</tbody>
<tbody *ngIf="configuration.data?.length == 0">
  <tr style="width: 100% !important">
    <td class="no-data-available" [attr.colspan]="numberOfColumns">No data available</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Construction of dtOptions**

```
    var pageSize = this.configuration.pageSize || 10;
if (this.configuration.ajax) {
  this.dtOptions = {
    // processing: true,
    ajax: (dtParameters: any, callback) => {
      var URL = this.configuration.ajax.URL;
      if (this.configuration.ajax) {
        var currentPage = (parseInt(dtParameters['start']) + parseInt(dtParameters['length'])) / pageSize;
        URL = `${URL}?page=${currentPage - 1}&pageSize=${pageSize}`
      }
      this.crud.get(URL, this.configuration.ajax.headers).subscribe((res) => {
        this.configuration.data = this.getObjectByPath(res);
        callback({
          recordsTotal: res['paging']['total'],
          recordsFiltered: res['paging']['total'],
          data: []
        })
      })
    },
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    bLengthChange: false,
    bFilter: true,
    bInfo: false,
    bAutoWidth: false,
    pageLength: pageSize,
    order: [],
    serverSide: true,
    pagingType: 'full_numbers',
    columns: this.configuration.columns,
    responsive: true,
    language: {
      search: 'Filter: '
    },
    buttons: [
      {
        extend: 'print',
        exportOptions: {
          columns: "thead th:not(.noExport)"
        }
      },
      {
        extend: 'excel',
        exportOptions: {
          columns: "thead th:not(.noExport)"
        }
      },
      {
        extend: 'csv',
        exportOptions: {
          columns: "thead th:not(.noExport)"
        }
      }
    ]
  };
} else if (this.configuration.data) {
  if (typeof this.configuration.data === 'object' && !(this.configuration.data instanceof Array)) {
    this.configuration.data = [this.configuration.data];
  }
  this.dtOptions = {
    bLengthChange: false,
    bFilter: true,
    bInfo: false,
    bAutoWidth: false,
    pageLength: pageSize,
    order: [],
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    pagingType: 'full_numbers',
    columns: this.configuration.columns,
    responsive: true,
    language: {
      search: 'Filter: '
    },
    buttons: [
      {
        extend: 'print',
        exportOptions: {
          columns: "thead th:not(.noExport)"
        }
      },
      {
        extend: 'excel',
        exportOptions: {
          columns: "thead th:not(.noExport)"
        }
      },
      {
        extend: 'csv',
        exportOptions: {
          columns: "thead th:not(.noExport)"
        }
      }
    ]
  };
}
```

**Current Problem**
[image]

**Expected Behavior**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue because i had some columns which i wanted to search but not display.

You need to use "visible: false" for the column and if you want to show them than apply the visibility to it.

```
this.datatableElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
  dtInstance.column(columnIndex).visible(true or false);
});
```

Comment: this is not exactly what I am searching for.  I need the columns to be hidden but to be able to display them with the (+) button at the right side of each row.  This is automatically done by data tables.  In my case I have this problem (I guess) because I fetch the data from backend directly.